# how to wait while animation is performing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, animation

i have two image view, called animation and instruction
animation image view for play animation
and instruction image view for display instruction

i want to do that when my animation is finished then i want change the image of instruction image view

```
 -(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{    

    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"vivacious%d.png",i] ] ];
        }
        self.animation.animationImages = array;
        self.animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;//0 for infinite loop
        self.animation.animationDuration = 1.5;

        [self.animation startAnimating];
        //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5];
        self.instruction.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ah.png"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{    

    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"vivacious%d.png",i] ] ];
        }

        self.animation.animationImages = array;
        self.animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;//0 for infinite loop
        self.animation.animationDuration = 1.5;

        [self.animation startAnimating];
        self.instruction.hidden = YES;

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(changeInstruction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use following method

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                     animations:^{
                         //code for animation start
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //code for animation end
                     }];
```

**OR** You can try following methods for waiting for specific time & then execute method with selector

```
[self.view performSelector:@selector(your_Method) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector with delay after first one completes or you can even use this line,

```
   [UIView setAnimationDelay:5.0]
```

This will start your animation after delay of 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

About your code I wonder to know what animation you used?

1）If you use Core Animation , you can achieve CAAnimation's delegate.

The delegate has a method called : `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag`, when the animation finished , it will be called. So you can change the image of instruction image view in it.

**But be careful , the CAAnimation's delegate is retain**

2）If you use UIView animation , it has a animation complete block called : `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`,you can change the image of instruction image view in the completion block